# Why is my $.each call returning more results than there are elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I'm having trouble doing a simple iterate through divs of a particular class.

There's two divs, but I'm getting 14 iterations.

```
  $(function() {
      $.each("div.container", function(){
         alert( "test" );
      });
   });
```

and the html

```
<div id="div1" class="container">

</div>

<div id="div2" class="container">

</div>
```

can anyone explain what i'm doing wrong? Thanks ahead

Comment: $.each : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ and $().each() : http://api.jquery.com/each/ are different

Comment: I think you get 13 iterations instead of 14. You are iterating the characters in 'div.container'. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
$(function() {
      $("div.container").each( function(){
         alert( "test" );
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("div.container").each( function(){
        alert( "test" );
    });
});
```

There is a ***big difference*** between [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

The first method is a generic iterator function that is used for iterating over arrays and objects, where the latter method is used for cycling through a collection of jQuery objects.

When you are calling `$.each('div.container')`, **you are actually passing each letter of the string as the function argument**. Since `div.container` contains 13 (yes, 13) characters, the iteration is called 13 times ([see example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/pEZFQ/)).

Comment: Thanks heaps for the details explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
      $.each($("div.container"), function(){
         alert( "test" );
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $.each()

You have to put the jquery objects in the parameter but not the selector text

```
      $(function() {
      $.each($("div.container"), function(){
         alert( "test" );
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.container').each(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

That's all you need really, haha. ;D